# ERROR: Could not build wheels for lxml, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, yfinance

I'm new with python and im trying to install the module of **yfinance** for my uni class, but I keep getting this error when trying to install it... anyone knows how to solve this problem?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDwH0.png)

Wanted to install yfinance module because when I try to install it in vs code i get the following error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yfinance

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text -- include the text itself directly in the question (formatted as a code sample). The error message asks a pertinent question ("Is libxml2 installed?"). If you're not sure how to answer that question, please give us more information about your environment (such as what OS/distribution you're using).

Answer (score 8):

This issue is getting resolved for me after doing the upgrade for setuptools.

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools

pip install lxml
```

I am using the python version 3.8.16. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm on 3.8.2 and it did not work

Answer (score 1):

pip install lxml==4.8.0

Try to install lxml 4.8 instead of lxml 4.9.
Version 4.9 has this issue

Answer (score 1):

Updating Python to 3.11 did it for me!

```
brew update && brew install python@3.11
```

Answer (score 0):

The `lxml` package seems to cause such errors when Xcode Command Line Tools are not correctly installed or some paths are missing/broken. As implied in your terminal, first try:

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

The command above will install the required packages if not installed already. If you receive the error `xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`, try resetting Xcode Command Line Tools as follows. It will reset the path to the Xcode Command Line Tools directory, which may help with the issue.

```
$ sudo xcode-select --reset
```

After you install/update Xcode Command Line Tools, try installing `lxml` separately to see if your issue is resolved.

```
$ pip install lxml
```

Comment: It did not work. I'm on 3.8.2

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to install a library that has **lxml** as a dependency and faced the same issue. Since I am using **Conda**, I executed the following command:

```
conda install -c anaconda lxml
```

This command instructs **Conda** to install the **lxml** package from the official Anaconda channel. It resolved the issue for me. I hope it helps you as well.