# How to install lxml on mac?

Tags: macos, pip, package, lxml, yfinance

I'd like to install lxml on my mac to run packages like yfinance and pandas_datareader. However, when I try "pip install lxml" I receive this error;

> "ERROR: Could not build wheels for lxml, which is required to install
> pyproject.toml-based projects".

Any help would appreciated on solving this issue!

I was expecting lxml to be installed on my mac.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot install Lxml on Mac OS X 10.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548011/cannot-install-lxml-on-mac-os-x-10-9)

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/76418822/407651