# can't install lxml on windows

Tags: python, pip, lxml

i need install lxml 4.9.2 because i use other library, but i have this error
ERROR: Could not build wheels for lxml, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
i use windows

i tried update pip, but it have lastest version
and update sdk
also i watch
[ERROR: Could not build wheels for lxml, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76418822/error-could-not-build-wheels-for-lxml-which-is-required-to-install-pyproject-t)

Comment: What python version do you use?? Have you tried 3.11 ?? [You might be out of luck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77139779/5640517)

Comment: thanks
I thought the commenter meant to update python to a newer version, I didn't even think about going back to 3 11

Comment: When posting errors, please always include the full traceback

Answer (score 0):

thanks
use 3.11 python version Instead of 3.12

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You should add why you sugest to downgrade. I guess the problem is because the package has not been compiled for the newer python version yet, right? something like that if that really is the case.